# Creating hyperlinks to another worksheet via matching of values

Tags: excel

**2 worksheets:**

1. List of user who are sitting at a table and each
   table has a unique ID.
2. Floor plan with the table ID.

I would like to create hyperlinks for each table ID, when clicked, will direct to the table on the floor plan and highlights the cell.

Table ID (Worksheet 1) search and match table ID (Worksheet 2), return cell position, create hyperlink in Worksheet 1.

Help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Any sample data and desired result will be appreciated.

Comment: Worksheet 1 (1 column of number from 1 to 100), Worksheet 2 (The number 1 to 100 is placed randomly on the worksheet). Now, I want to create a hyperlink for each number in Worksheet 1, such that when it is clicked, it will redirect to the number in Worksheet 2 and highlighting it. The question is, how do I create the hyperlink? =HYPERLINK('what should i fill in here')

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment, `Column A` of `Sheet1` has values 1 to 100 in ascending order.

[image]

In `Column A` of your `Sheet2` you have numbers 1 to 100 in random order.

[image]

Now, to create the hyperlink, enter the following formula in `Cell B1` of  `Sheet1` and drag/copy it down as required

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH($A1, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100, 0), 1), $A1)
```

[image]

To take care of error when no match is found, use:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH($A1, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100, 0), 1), $A1),"")
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy comment! Another thing to add, if the values in Worksheet 2 is not in a single column, spread out in different columns and rows randomly, will this work? Or I just change to this =HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH($A1, Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$100, 0), 1), $A1)